# How to add new row as first row of the table in DataTable plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, datatable

For my requirement I am using DataTable.js plugin for display data in table.
I am using the below code to add a new row in that table.

```
var new_row = table.row.add({
                "select": '<input type="checkbox" />',
                "name": '<input type="text" 
placeholder="Enter Name" />',
                "position": '<input type="text" 
placeholder="Enter position" />',
                "salary": '<input type="text" 
placeholder="Enter Salary" />',
                "start_date": '<input type="text" 
placeholder="Enter Start Date" />',
                "office": '<input type="text" 
placeholder="Enter Office" />',
                "extn": '<input type="text" 
placeholder="Enter Extn" />',
                "action": '<input data-click="toggle" type="button" 
value="View Details" /> <input data-click="remove" type="button"    
value="Remove" />'
            }).draw().node();

            $(new_row).css('background', 'red');
```

The code works fine.

ISSUE: The new row has added as the last row in that table. What I am trying to do is the new row has to be added as the first row.

Can anyone help me to findout the solution?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Datatable is always order its row depending on **sorting** attribute.
so if you want your new row display on top of table then you have to set your new row'a attribute such as it accept the sorting and displayed at top.
**eg. if sorting attribute is created date then your new row must have the lateset created date.**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(new_row).prepend(table_id);
```

```js
$(new_row).prepend("#taable_id");
```